# Optimal refactor of divisibles from map

Tags: sorting, go

I have a function that takes input of packs which is a map of the pack size and the quantity and it takes a total quantity for an order.

I need to get all the divisibles for the pack sizes, remove all the under 1 values, and then pick the best divisible which is the lowest number remaining. This number is the key from the supplied packsizes

Note: I have a function further up the trace which eliminates any possibility of there not being a divisible.

Code:

```
func optimalDivisble(packs map[int]int, oq int) (int, error) {
    divisables := make(map[int]float64)
    for key := range packs {
        divisables[key] = float64(oq) / float64(key)
    }

    // Remove zero divisibles
    filteredDivisibles := make(map[int]float64)
    for key, divisable := range divisables {
        if divisable >= 1 {
            filteredDivisibles[key] = divisable
        }
    }

    //  Get divisables
    var divisableSlice []float64
    for _, filteredDivisible := range filteredDivisibles {
        divisableSlice = append(divisableSlice, filteredDivisible)
    }

    sort.Float64s(divisableSlice)
    for key, filteredDivisible := range filteredDivisibles {
        if filteredDivisible == divisableSlice[0] {
            return key, nil
        }
    }

    return 0, errors.New("Could not find a divisable for quantity")
}
```

Could someone help refactor this, as seeing 3 for loops doesn't seem ideal. What would be more idiomatic to Go?

Comment: All you need is the minimum in the filtered list, so you don't even need to create maps/slices for this.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks, would you be able to give me an example? I'm looking at https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Min but not sure how I'd fit it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process the packs, compute the min divisible and get the key for it in a single loop. You don't need the intermediate steps:

```
    var minDiv float64
    var minKey int
    minSet:=false
    for key := range packs {
       divisable:=float64(oq) / float64(key)
       if divisable>=1 {
          if minDiv>divisable || !minSet {
             minDiv=divisable
             minKey=key
             minSet=true
          }
       }
    }
    // minKey is what you need
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a habit of over engineering, really helpful to see another approach